# C# XML to dropdownBox

Tags: c#, xml

Returned XML from URL:

```
<root>
<APIVersion>0.1</APIVersion>
<resource>persons</resource>
<search>givenname</search>
<query>andreas</query>
<limit>400</limit>
<results>
<item>
<persons>
<personId>21168</personId>
<givenName>Andreas</givenName>
<familyName>Garpe</familyName>
<email>andreas.garpe@t-fk.no</email>
<mobilePhone/>
<workPhone/>
<positions>...</positions>
</persons>
</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
<item>...</item>
</results>
</root>
```

(Keep in mind that "item" is the objects with personnel info.)

I have a textbox defined as *bunifuTextbox1*.

I input a name, and it returns the names from the returned XML result and put all the names returned into a dropdown box.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string address = "http://ws.t-fk.no/?resource=persons&search=givenname&string=" + bunifuTextbox1.text;

    XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
    doc1.Load(address);
    XmlElement root = doc1.DocumentElement;
    XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/results/item");

    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        string tempf = node["persons"]["givenName"].InnerText;
        bunifuDropdown1.AddItem(tempf);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why this doesen't work. Any help?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is not working?

Comment: Also, please include your XML in the question, as text.

Comment: Not appearing in the dropbox, am I adding the wrong object, using AddItem() wrongly or accessing the XML objects improperly?

Comment: Is my answer useful? It addresses your XPath issue. Did it fix your problem? If not, please provide more information about the `bunifuDropdown1` control.

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is incorrect.
Instead of

```
 XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/results/item");
```

try

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("results/item");
```

or

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("./results/item");
```

or

```
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("//results/item");
```

Use `"results/item"` or `"./results/item"` for an `item` element that is a child of a `results` element that is a child of the root node.

Using `"//results/item"` will select `item` elements that are children of `results` elements where the `results` element is anywhere in the XML.